# help with requested paint finish

Tags: texturing, shaders, procedural

I've been asked to reproduce a paint finish such as the image shown, I have tried using a texture but when it is scaled over a large area the repeat becomes obvious. should this been done procedurally if so, can someone give me a hint as I am fairly new to using nodes.

thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add that link in the question.

Comment: will do, thanks.

Comment: there is a node group named "PoliigonUberMapping node" available that randomly rotates the tiles of the texture to break the repeating pattern. It works well for irregular textures like your smudges. Have a look here: https://youtu.be/-VgtSL5ZpYc